# configure Android WIFI over USB

Tags: android, usb, wifi

I have an Android device that has a WIFI adapter but no screen and no input devices. I want to use it as a silent server in my local network that runs / offers some services and will eventually be configurable via the internet. The service app will be pre-installed and launch upon boot. The problem is the initial configuration (mainly join the local WIFI network).

My idea is: Develop a Java GUI app that is used for the initial setup via USB.

Let's assume I get the desktop app to find and communicate with the Android service via the [ADK](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) (I will be happy to share here once I succeed). That way I will be able to use my screen & keyboard to configure it. Now the problem is:

How can I (on the Android device) obtain a list of WIFI netorks that the Android device finds and how can I tell it to connect to a selected network (with a provided password)?

Is there maybe a better way to achieve what I am trying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class should be helpful:

> This class provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity. Get an instance of this class by calling Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE). It deals with several categories of items:
>
> - The list of configured networks. The list can be viewed and updated, and attributes of individual entries can be modified.
> - The currently active Wi-Fi network, if any. Connectivity can be established or torn down, and dynamic information about the state of the network can be queried.
> - Results of access point scans, containing enough information to make decisions about what access point to connect to.
> - It defines the names of various Intent actions that are broadcast upon any sort of change in Wi-Fi state.
>
> This is the API to use when performing Wi-Fi specific operations. To perform operations that pertain to network connectivity at an abstract level, use ConnectivityManager.

Comment: wow, that was easy. Indeed that API seems to provide all the necessary functionality (scan for available networks, configure network with password, enable network).